# Rotary Encoder for Android GPIO

Tags: low-power, encoder, rotary

I'm not too sure if this is the place to ask but I'm not sure where else this question belongs. I'm trying to hook up a rotary encoder to an Android dev board's GPIO pins, although I'm having trouble finding the right encoder.

I would like one that uses quadrature (incremental) and ideally an optical one (will settle for mechanical if necessary). The problem is that the GPIO operates at 1.8V and anything more can damage the device. I spent some time looking on [Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.ca/product-search/en/sensors-transducers/encoders/1966131?FV=a4019a%2Cfff4001e%2Cfff80033&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=0&pbfree=0&rohs=0&k=rotary+encoder&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25&pkeyword=rotary+encoder) and it seems like all the optical encoders require a higher voltage and the mechanical ones are all rated at ~5V or more. I have found some from TE [here](http://www.te.com/usa-en/plp/rotary-encoders/Y30y4.html?q=&n=42572&type=products&p=2&samples=N) although they don't seem to have any distributors for them in North America. Where might I find what I'm looking for / does anyone have a solution?

Comment: If this is a low cycles per revolution one you could probably use a simple voltage divider.  Otherwise there are a range of active level shifters.   At a higher cycles per revolution you may want an external quadrature counter chip or slave micro to catch the events and query the count periodically from your android/linux system without the same concern about missing events due to interrupt latency.

Comment: Your approach depends on whether your GPIO is 5V tolerant or not.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It can use fairly low cycles per revolution however I only have access to the 1.8V power rail as it is getting its power from the device so I can't really use the voltage divider. You make a good point about latency though. I was looking into how to access the GPIO pins from inside android and it seems like I'll need to get the value from `/sys/class/gpio` which I'm hoping will be fast enough.

Comment: @ScottSeidman It isn't. Anything above 1.8V may damage the device.

Comment: Then you need to use any method of converting the logic levels.  There are many drivers in the 74-family that would do the job nicely.

Comment: Running a tiny boost converter from the 1.8 to power the encoder is an idea, but why not tap the board's power input or USB host port power?  Simplest would be a mechanical encoder at 1.8v.  Also you want the gpio *interrupt* interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a mechanical contact incremental rotary encoder. Many many are available in low PPR (pulses per revolution) for use as user input devices. They require no power supply unto themselves. You can simply wire them up to your GPIOs as switch contacts to GND and with a pullup to the 1.8V that your GPIOs operate with.

Answer (score 0):

You need something simple. Look here: [US Digital](http://www.usdigital.com/products/encoders). They are simple, single-ended or differential.

Comment: These all have supply voltage ranges from 4.5-5.5V.

Comment: Like all encoders i know. Sorry, i missed. What's wrong with 5v?